# SparkAR set position with screen tap and screen pan?

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Ok I have a plane tracker where I manipulate the position via screen pan but also want to set the position of the plane with screen tap. You cant have multiple nodes set the position of an object, so I have a null object as the child of the plane tracker.

[image]

Because I move the plane tracker with screen tap and the null object with screen pan, I need to reset the null object to (0,0,0) every time I screen tap, else the null object's local position is way off. I tried doing that with a pulse, but it does not work:

[image]

Is there a way to have a plane tracker's position set with screen pan AND screen tap?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any nullObject here! Just use this graph to get pan/tap at the same time.

[image: GRAPH]